# Page level Deadlock on same delete query

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

In SQL Server I am issuing the following query:

```
DELETE FROM TableA WHERE tableB_id IN (SELECT ID from TableB WHERE FileID = @P0)
```

The query is being called in parallel by multiple processes and which is causing a page-level deadlock issue.

I also have NONCLUSTERED INDEX defined on tableB_id column of TableA which is FK as well.

I am also sharing deadlock XML below. Can anyone help me how can I prevent this deadlock?

```
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="process1a0de90e108" />
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="process1a0de90e108" taskpriority="0" logused="2436" waitresource="PAGE: 6:1:17997419 " waittime="4726" ownerId="3967991339" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-06-07T21:18:08.423" XDES="0x19fa9470428" lockMode="U" schedulerid="2" kpid="7264" status="suspended" spid="2460" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2021-06-07T21:18:08.777" lastbatchcompleted="2021-06-07T21:18:08.777" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.777" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="test_app-7c98f79f44-mz8jf" hostpid="0" loginname="test_user" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="3967991339" currentdb="6" currentdbname="p01-ardb" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x9453568569bd0807" queryplanhash="0x1d037286349af98c" line="1" stmtstart="24" stmtend="178" sqlhandle="0x0200000098b1eb2a734675ebd923e42ae1e8765c543d5e020000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
(@P0 bigint)DELETE FROM TableA WHERE tableB_id IN (SELECT ID from TableB WHERE FileID = @P0)   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process1a0f2886108" taskpriority="0" logused="117716" waitresource="PAGE: 6:1:17915872 " waittime="4747" ownerId="3967991523" transactionname="implicit_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-06-07T21:18:08.470" XDES="0x1a015ef8428" lockMode="U" schedulerid="4" kpid="51220" status="suspended" spid="2425" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2021-06-07T21:18:08.853" lastbatchcompleted="2021-06-07T21:18:08.853" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.853" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="test_app-7c98f79f44-mz8jf" hostpid="0" loginname="test_user" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="3967991523" currentdb="6" currentdbname="p01-ardb" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x9453568569bd0807" queryplanhash="0x1d037286349af98c" line="1" stmtstart="24" stmtend="178" sqlhandle="0x0200000098b1eb2a734675ebd923e42ae1e8765c543d5e020000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
(@P0 bigint)DELETE FROM TableA WHERE tableB_id IN (SELECT ID from TableB WHERE FileID = @P0)   </inputbuf>
    </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="17997419" dbid="6" subresource="FULL" objectname="f8e7ffa7-ac56-4e56-8ca2-70672c9fe337.AR.TableA" id="lock19e62889280" mode="UIX" associatedObjectId="72057594635354112">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process1a0f2886108" mode="UIX" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process1a0de90e108" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="17915872" dbid="6" subresource="FULL" objectname="f8e7ffa7-ac56-4e56-8ca2-70672c9fe337.AR.TableA" id="lock19da5da9780" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594635354112">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process1a0de90e108" mode="U" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process1a0f2886108" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Index definition as follows:

```
Table B
index_name, index_description,                                    index_keys                                            

CIX_TableB  clustered, unique located on datePartitionScheme    , TestDate(-)
IX01_TableB nonclustered located on datePartitionScheme               FileID
PK_TableB   nonclustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY      ID

Table A

index_name, index_description,                                   index_keys  
                                                
IX01_TableA nonclustered located on PRIMARY                        tableB_id 
PK_TableA   clustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY       ID
```

Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE TableA(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [tableB_id ] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TableA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE TableB  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_01] FOREIGN KEY([tableB_id])
REFERENCES [AR].TableB ([ID])

CREATE TABLE [TableB](
    [FileID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BookgDt] [date] NOT NULL,
    [ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](4000) NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_TableB] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [TableB] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_01]  DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR [Sequence_01]) FOR [ID]
GO
```

Comment: I think deadlocks would be incredibly difficult to troubleshoot via this platform - I suspect there will be more involved than just the one statement where the deadlocked process is ultimately being kicked out.  Also, perhaps https://dba.stackexchange.com/ would be a better forum, in general, for a question like this (if you haven't posted there already)

Comment: Is there an index on `TableB.FileID`? How many rows are normally returned by the subquery? The optimizer will have a hard time estimating how many rows come back, which can lead to sub-optimal strategies for deletion. If possible, consider splitting the query (select affected IDs into a table variable or temp table first, then to the `DELETE FROM` on that table `WITH RECOMPILE`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, TableB.FileID also has NONCLUSTERED INDEX and sub query returns around 25K records :)

Comment: Have you any index on the FileId column?

Comment: @ESAT Yes, I do have index on File column but SSMS is suggesting to add index on FileId when i run query with execution plan.

Comment: Updated Index definition in question

Comment: It can be useful to add your TableA and TableB creation scripts because your deadlock XML shows that the deadlock occurred because of the update lock. So in this case, SQL Server may modify the foreign key columns after the delete operation.

Comment: @ESAT Updated TableA and TableB creation scripts

Comment: Could check the foreign key constraint definition there is not tableB_id column in tableB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233600/discussion-between-junaid-akhtar-and-esat).

Comment: The execution plan would help here, please share it via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. It looks like, at a guess, you have a big scan on `TableB` to find the right `FileId`, and a big scan on `TableA` to find the corresponding `ID`. Indexes on the correct columns would probably fix this. `TableA (tableB_id)` and `TableB (FileID)`

Comment: @Charlieface Things are already like that what you are suggesting.

Comment: Well show the execution plan and let's see if the indexes are being used

Comment: Deadlock resolved after removing nonclustered located on column tableB_id  of TableA